# What is the best way to copy S3 bucket including all the versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy S3 bucket's objects across region. My source bucket is having version enabled and I need my destination bucket **should retain all the versions** present in my source bucket(though I think we can't preserve the actual timestamp while copying). I would prefer to have some officially supported tool.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 [Cross-Region Replication (CRR)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) will do this for you. In fact, it requires versioning to be activated.

However, it will only take effect *after* it is activated. Any existing objects and versions will *not* be replicated.

Comment: CRR seems work if you plan ahead of time, but my requirement is to sync all the files, including the versions of an existing bucket to a newly created bucket in different region. I am quite surprised to see that this trivial requirement is so difficult to tackle in aws.

Comment: Even if you were to manually copy the old versions across, they would receive different version IDs. (I wonder if IDs are kept with CRR?) If that is acceptable, you could write a script to iterate through every version of every object and copy it across, then use CRR for future replication.

Comment: Not only version id but the last modified timestamp would also change, though I am not really bother about that but my priority is to have a standard tool to migrate some GB of data in production within stipulated downtime

Comment: It's unusual to rely on "old versions" so much -- it's normally just a safety precaution in case something important gets overwritten. It shouldn't be used as an intentional storage method, simply because versions are harder to access and manipulate than base objects. From a backup perspective, hopefully the latest versions will suffice. Or, use a lifecycle policy to archive the old versions to Glacier. The most common uses for CRR are having data in another region closer to processing that uses it, and replicating to another account in case of incorrect deletion.

Comment: Upvoting for suggesting the best practices around S3.

Comment: Late update, but as of 2022 you can use S3 Batch Replication to replicate existing object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-batch-replication-batch.html